# Newton derivative of the distance function in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If we consider the distance function $d$, where $d(x)=dist(x,\partial\Omega)=\inf_{y\in\Omega}\|x-y\|_2$, how would one calculate the derivative in some direction $v$, i.e.

$\large\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{\|x+\varepsilon v -y\|_2-\|x-y\|_2}{\varepsilon}$

My problem is dealing with the square root, since $\|x-y\|_2=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$,

thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $d$ is not everywhere differentiable. It is differentiable at $x$ for which the distance-minimizing $y$ is unique. Fix such $x_0$ and let $y^*$ be the minimizer. Observe that near $x_0$, 
$$
d(x) = \|x-y^*\|_2+o(\|x-x_0\|)
$$
Therefore, the derivative of $d$ at $x_0$ is the same as the derivative of $\|x-y^*\|_2$. To find the latter, differentiate the squared norm first: 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{\|x+\varepsilon v -y^*\|_2^2-\|x-y^*\|_2^2}{\varepsilon} = 2\langle x-y^*, v \rangle  $$
Then take the square root and apply the  Chain rule: 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{\|x+\varepsilon v -y^*\|_2-\|x-y\|_2}{\varepsilon} = \frac{\langle x-y^*, v \rangle}{\|x-y^*\|}  $$

Comment: I forgot to add that the domain $\Omega$, will be convex, or at least closed, so I believe the minimiser will be unique, so even with this type of derivative, the chain rule holds? Thank you for your answer, very helpful.

Comment: @ellya The directional derivative is just the ordinary derivative of a function of one variable $(\varepsilon)$. Yes, chain rule applies.